# Is there nothing that can't be made from wood? (Can you top this?)

Tags: design

A couple days ago I had an idea for a question to embrace the spirit of April Fools day.  I wanted to write a supposedly serious question about an absurd wood project with odd, tongue in cheek, problems.  This would give viewers a chance to have some fun with clever answers. It turns out the joke was on me.  As I checked out every odd idea I had for the wood project, I found that someone had actually done it in wood!.  It then occurred to me just how great woodworking can be.  The media, wood, is kind of mundane, but the results are often incredible.

I know that this is intended as an answer site for specific woodworking questions based on facts and avoids open ended questions, but I find the creativity in the woodworking community remarkable and couldn't resist asking.

Close this if you must, but I would invite others to share their most incredible woodworking finds as answers. I've provided a couple answers to get things started.but please add more.  Don't simply post a picture, share why it inspires or amuses you.

Comment: a wooden fireplace

Comment: While the topic is interesting, I have to vote to close.  Per the [Help Center](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), `Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.`

Comment: @grfrazee I respect your concern, but I would argue that inspiring woodworkers does not diminish the site. One way this site differs from some other stackexchange sites is that woodworking encompasses a very visual creativity. I believe encouraging free thinking in design is a positive for the site.  The question is specifically designed to avoid "Look what I made" subjects but rather celebrate and expand on ideas for what is possible.

Comment: Encouraging creativity is all well and good, but it's not the [real purpose of this SE](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.`  Understand that I'm not trying to throw the rule book in your face, just trying to keep the content here consistent to the site's purpose.

Comment: @grfrazee I understand and realize I am stretching the boundaries.  I won't be offended if it is closed, but believe that it is important to stretch boundaries from time to time.  This is a small site and I would like to stimulate its growth.  I do not want to make this an opinion forum, but I do want to attract participants.

Comment: @grfrazee  I would suggest we leave it open for a while and see if it has a positive impact with visitors.

Comment: I would like to discuss this more and have commented in The Workshop forum.

Comment: Have to agree, not an answerable question, take it to discussion.

Comment: Hey folks, let's at least give this one a day of glory in honor of the day, then perhaps @Ashlar can delete it, and then we can, as a group decide upon the restriction on free and open  discussion established in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

Wood Automobiles. I remember woodies being a thing. Cars, usually trucks or wagons with wood panels applied to the side, and really great for conveying surfers to the beach.  However, these cars are something special, a marriage between love of woodcraft and the automobile. The amount of carving and freehand shaping needed is atonishing.I think Tesla should consider wood for the Tesla IV.

[image]

http://www.ukiedaily.com/blog/2012/07/ukrainian-wooden-car-for-sale/

[image]

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-516687/The-worlds-wooden-supercar-faster-Porsche-Lamborghini.html

Answer (score 0):

Wood submarine.  Wood floats!  The idea of making a submersible expresses wit, dogged determination, and a lack of understanding of basic physics!!The question of why someone thought this was a good idea amazes me.

[image]
 http://www.travelinginspain.com/barcelona/ictineo.htm

Comment: Ballast is a thing.

Comment: Not all wood floats. Ironwood OS one of the species which is denser than water; try  it yourself with a scrap of ipe decking. (Old story about tropical fisherman who marks a favorite spot by tying fishing line to stick and rock and tossing overboard: ironwood stick sinks, pumice rock floats.)

Comment: Just as you can build a boat out of concrete (it's a common engineering challenge in college), you can build a submarine out of wood. Whether an object floats or not is a matter of it weighing less than the amount of water it displaces. It has nothing to do with the materials it is built out of (except insofar as the weight of those materials as compared to the weight of the water displaced).

Answer (score 0):

People have done alot with wood. As for carvings, 3D cutting boards and so much more. There is tons of stuff out there to blow your mind!

[image]

http://tagwoodworking.com/projects/3d-cutting-board-5/

[image]

https://m.viator.com/photo/bangkok/floating-markets-and-bridge-on-river-kwai-tour-from-bangkok/0-8-3685BKK29C/photo.htm

Stuff like this.

Comment: Share your favorites

Comment: Okay hold a min and I will update